# PHP MySQLi Email Form

Tags: php, forms, email, web, mysqli

I need to being by letting you all know that I am at the very beginning stages of learning web programming. I understand enough to read the code and know what it is doing. I am learning using courses, online training, and "real world" training.

I am having an issue with a contact form I am attempting to create. The company I work for has several websites that use contact forms. I used the contact form code that has been working on the other website, but we have changed our host beginning with this new host and they use MySQLi rather than MySQL. When I use the following code, it posts to the database and works as expected.

```
<?php
//hake yachts contact

//connection

$con =   mysqli_connect("localhost","hakeyachtcontact","hakeyachtcontact","hakeyachtcontact");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//insert
$sql="INSERT INTO hakeyachtcontact (firstName, lastName, email,  boatModel)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstName]','$_POST[lastName]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[boatModel]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

Now...when I add the following code, an email doesn't send and the previous functionality that worked (posting data to the database) stops working.

```
//email
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "joshua.delph@heartlandfpg.com";
    $email_subject = "Hake Yachts Website Contact";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['firstName']) ||
       !isset($_POST['lastName']) ||
       !isset($_POST['email']) ||
       !isset($_POST['boatModel'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

$firstName = $_POST['firstName']; // required
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];// required
$email = $_POST['email'];// required
$boatModel = $_POST['boatModel'];// required


    $error_message = "";
    if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){ 
   $error_message .= 'The email you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
   $string_exp = "^[a-z .'-]+$";
  if(!eregi($string_exp,$firstName)) {
    $error_message .= 'The name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  $string_exp = "^[a-z .'-]+$";
  if(!eregi($string_exp,$lastName)) {
    $error_message .= 'The name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($firstName)."\n";
    $email_message .= "email: ".clean_string($lastName)."\n";
    $email_message .= "phone: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "comments: ".clean_string($boatModel)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

//send
header("Location: thankyou.html");
```

I have a sneaking suspicion that this is due to the differences between MySQL and MySQLi, but I am not confident that is the case. I have searched using Google and haven't found anything that has helped up to this point and I have tried several different solutions I found online. I am really at loss trying to figure this out.

I am also open to other solutions for submitting web forms via email.

I truly appreciate any help anyone can provide. I am willing to go through tutorials or anything else that would help me learn.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it throw any errors, or do anything at all? The code you posted is missing a closing brace from the `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {`, but that may have just been left off in the posting.

Comment: It's isn't throwing any errors at all. Just goes to the "blank" contact.php page. It doesn't post to the database or re-direct to the "Thank You" page. It is really strange. We have tested using 'echo' to no avail. The 'echo' works after the first bit of text, but it doesn't work when we add the other code.

Comment: It was the stinking missing closing bracket. It works now!!!!! YOU ARE AMAZING!!!! If you would add it as an answer, I will mark it as answered by you.

Comment: Done. Glad it helped! As a hint, find an IDE with error checking (Eclipse/Aptana/NetBeans). I used Notepad++ for years, which has folding but not checking, but I missed many errors like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing closing brace on `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {`. Just add it where you need to close off the check.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this. Everything appears to be working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO hakeyachtcontact (firstName, lastName, email,  boatModel)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstName]','$_POST[lastName]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[boatModel]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

to:

```
$firstname = $con->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);
$lastname = $con->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);
$email = $con->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$boatmodel = $con->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['boatModel']);

$sql="INSERT INTO hakeyachtcontact (firstName, lastName, email,  boatModel)
VALUES
('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$boatmodel')";

if ($con->query($sql) === FALSE)
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

Comment: Or use parametrization.